# FBNativeAd and nativeAdViewWithNativeAd returns frame with size CGZero

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm attempting to use the Facebook SDK to show Native Ads within my app.

However it appears that a frame with size CGZero is returned.

```
- (void)showNativeAd
{
    [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"123"];

    FBNativeAd *nativeAd = [[FBNativeAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:@"456"];
    nativeAd.delegate = self;

    [nativeAd loadAd];
}

- (void)nativeAdDidLoad:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    UIView *adView;

    if(self.useSmallView){

        adView = [FBNativeAdView nativeAdViewWithNativeAd:nativeAd
                                                 withType:FBNativeAdViewTypeGenericHeight100];

    }else{

        adView = [FBNativeAdView nativeAdViewWithNativeAd:nativeAd
                                                 withType:FBNativeAdViewTypeGenericHeight300];
    }

    [nativeAd registerViewForInteraction:adView withViewController:self];

    [self.view addSubview:adView];
}
```

returns

```
<FBAdGenericHeight100View: 0x13df70e20; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x13df6e6e0>>
```

Comment: Just in case, have you created your placement ids as stipulated here? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/getting-started. Are you getting any errors?